# javascript clock trouble running timer function?

Tags: javascript

Was wondering where I am going wrong with this snippet of code, basically the startTime() only gets run once and thats it so the clock doesnt update. Can anyone advise how I can fix this?

JS

```
function startTime(){
  var today=new Date();
  var h=today.getHours();
  var m=today.getMinutes();
  var s=today.getSeconds();
  // add a zero in front of numbers<10
  m=checkTime(m);
  s=checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
  t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
  }

  function checkTime(i){
  if (i<10)
    {
    i="0" + i;
    }
  return i;
  }
```

HTML

```
    <body onload="startTime()">

<p>Date</p>
<?php echo date("d/m/y"); ?>

<p>Time</p>
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Link http://bit.ly/IC9ohX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have a problem with the scoping of your functions.

Short solution: Change

```
t=setTimeout( 'startTime()',500);
```

to this.

```
t = setTimeout( startTime, 500 );
```

Explanation:

The function `startTime` is defined within the function for `window.onload` and is only visible within that function (and functions within it)!

In your code JavaScript waits the 500ms and then tries to execute the code `startTime()`. It searches for the function `startTime` in the global scope (which is the execution scope of `setTimeout`) and can't find any reference, thus resulting in an error and your code not working.

My code passes the reference of the function `startTime` to `setTimeout`. This way the engine does not have to search for the handler and can't fail at that point. At the point where `setTimeout` is called, you are in the scope of `window.unload`, thus the engine knows of the function `startTime` and can cope with the handler passed to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` waits the specified amount of time, does its job, then stops.
You want `setInterval`, which repeats the same job indefinitely.

EDIT: Sorry, I brainfarted while reading your code.  Didn't realize you were calling setTimeout at the end of the function.

There's still a valid use case to use setInterval instead of setTimeout though.  Suppose your function itself takes 2 milliseconds to complete.  Rather than updating every half a second, your clock is actually updating every 502 milliseconds.  So, after 100 iterations, it will be executing .2 seconds off from where it should be.  It's probably not noticeable, but a setInterval of 1 second would make your clock actually appear to tick every second, as it should.